# Hide git mirror remote from logs

Tags: git

I have a remote setup as simply a backup destination, I push to it at regular intervals with the `--mirror` option. Additionally, I have an alias setup that works on all of my machines that I use to pretty-print my log graph on the command line. I'd like this to ignore the remote I have setup for my mirror, but I can't specify this in my alias because the name of my mirror remote isn't the same in all of my clones. Is there a repository-agnostic way of setting this up? Would be nice if there was an option to `git remote add` to tell it to be a dumb link or something.

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're doing with the different items here, but remotes can be placed into "remote groups", if that helps.  You could put the mirror(s) in a different group from other remotes that you do want graphed, and then work based on group-names (which would be the same everywhere) rather than remote-names (which vary).

Comment: @torek This sounds close to what I want. Two questions: 1) How do I assign a remote to a group, 2) How do I exclude a remote-group from my logs?

Comment: A group just lists the remotes, e.g., `git config remote.pair "origin upstream"`.  For the logs, well, I have no idea, I don't know how you're doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I exclude a remote-group from my logs?

I would:

- read the value of your remote group (`git config remote.pair`)
- unset it (for the log command to not see that remote): `git config --unset remote.pair`
- perform the `git log` command
- reset it: `git config remote.par $valueread`